# Why are all the pictureBoxes in flowLayoutPanel controls collection displaying the same image?

Tags: c#, linked-list, controlcollection

I have a flowLayoutPanel that has pictureBoxes in it. I add multiple PictureBoxes at run time like this:

```
        while (flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count < 10)
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new PictureBox());
        }
```

I have a function that makes the "Image" property of each control equal to the "Image" values of Images in the LinkedList. The idea is to call the method when I want to add a new image to an Image Queue. When I pass a new Image to the function all the picture boxes in the FlowLayoutPanel display the **last image** in the linked list rather than the appropriate image in the LinkedList. I **HAVE** confirmed that LinkedList does in fact contain different images at each position. It is like all of the PictureBoxes in the FlowLayoutPanel are referencing the last one added.

```
    internal void AddImage(ThermalImage thermalImage)
    {
        thermalImages.AddFirst(thermalImage);

        while (thermalImages.Count > 10)
        {
            thermalImages.RemoveLast();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < thermalImages.Count; i++)
        {
            PictureBox p = (PictureBox)flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[i];
            p.Image = thermalImages.ElementAt(i).Image;
        }
    }
```

Is my initialization for populating the FlowLayoutPanel wrong? 
Is the way I am assigniung values to the PictureBox controls wrong?
Why are all the PictureBoxes referencing the same Image?

Comment: Where in the code are you calling : AddImage(ThermalImage thermalImage)

Comment: Works for me...show us more code.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I solved the issue. It had something to do with the FLIR ThermalImage object. If I saved the ThermalImage object to disk and then reloaded it to a new ThermalImageFile object then it works fine. Thank you for confirming that the logic above is good. That we the confirmation I needed to get it figured out.